# Variable is not defined when trying to pass it through onClick()

Tags: javascript, jquery, compiler-errors

I'm new to Js so don't know how to solve this. After displaying my macros with `$.each` like **Code example 1** I want with help of `onClick()` insert macro body to input text box using **Code example 2** but it throws:
 `Uncaught ReferenceError: body is not definedat HTMLDivElement.onclick`
Strange thing that when I'm passing `macroId` as value it passes well and inserts it into Input textbox.

**Code example 1**

```
function loadMacros() {
$.getJSON("api/Macros/",
    (data) => {
        $.each(data, (key, val) => {
            var macroid = val.macroId;
            var name = val.name;
            var body = val.macroBody;
            var userid = val.userId;
            $(`
                <div class="macrobox" onClick="insertMacroToText(${body})">
                <div id="" style="text-align : left">
                <div>
                <p><b>${name}</b>
                <a class=" glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" href="Messenger/MacroDetails/${macroid}" ></a>
                <a class=" glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" href="Messenger/EditMacro/${macroid}"></a>
                <a class=" glyphicon glyphicon-minus" onClick="deleteMacro(${macroid})" ></a>      
                </p>
                </div>
                <p style="text-align:left">${body}</p> 
                </div>
                </div>
            `)
            .appendTo($('#macros'));
        });
    });
}
```

**Code example 2**

```
function insertMacroToText(body) {
    var input = document.getElementById("textInput");
    input.value = body;
}
```

Comment: Your `getstatus` that is causing the error is nowhere in the code you posted. Can you post the part of the code that defines that function?

Comment: What is `getstatus`? It's not defined anywhere in your code. Also, if `body` is a string you need to wrap it in quotes in the template literal where you provide it to `insertMacroToText()`. Better yet, get rid of the ugly and outtdated `on*` event attributes and use delegated event handlers instead.

Comment: getstatus is exact body text which i trying to pass, sorry, my bad will edit it

Comment: try `console.log(body);` just before `$(\`...`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Tried to wrap in quotes but still writes that unidentified

Comment: @KrzysztofJaniszewski consolle  output is good, it shows exact value